# 'Path' object has no attribute 'currentPosition'

Tags: ros

I have a very strange case here. I have a python node that has a class with several attributes one of which is `currentPosition`. My code runs without problems for the initial iterations and very often breaks before the last iteration. I have identified the problem segment and where everything goes wrong,  it is in the constructor!

```
print "path.currentPosition and path.speed",path.currentPosition,path.speed

newPath=Path(path.currentPosition,path.speed)

print "newPath.currentPosition and newPath.speed",newPath.currentPosition,newPath.speed
```

I will copy the function in which I see the error:

---

```
def computePathWithoutWaypoints(self, path, waypointsToExclude):
    '''! Compute the path based on the current path but without considering some tasks
    
    It have to recompute the path in some cases using the motion_planner so it can be slow.
    Necessary to estimateRobotLossWithoutWaypoints()
    '''

    print "path.currentPosition, path.speed",path.currentPosition, path.speed
    newPath=Path(path.currentPosition, path.speed)
    print "NEW path.currentPosition, path.speed", newPath.currentPosition,newPath.speed
    
    i=0
    lastAdded=-1
    conflict=False
    for waypoint in path:
        # print waypoint
        if waypoint in waypointsToExclude:
            conflict=True
            i+=1
            continue

        if conflict==False:
            newPath.append(path.waypointsPlanned[i],path.timePlanned[i])
        elif i-lastAdded==1:
            newPath.append(path.waypointsPlanned[i],updateTime=True)
        else:
            pathToWaypoint,timeToWaypoint=self.computePathToWaypoint(waypoint, startingPoint=newPath.lastPlannedPosition(),startingTime=newPath.lastPlannedTime())
            newPath.append(pathToWaypoint,timeToWaypoint)

        i+=1
        lastAdded=i-1

    return newPath
```

---

Here is my Class (off course parts of it):

```
class Path:

    waypointsPlanned=0
    timePlanned=0
    currentPosition=0
    speed=0.3
    
    def __init__(self,currentPosition,speed):
        
        self.waypointsPlanned=[]
        self.timePlanned=[]
        self.currentPosition=currentPosition
        self.speed=speed
```

Now, I've checked all the indentations and made sure there is not a problem there. I can't understand what is happening inside this constructor. I get meaningful and correct values in the first print and upon the second one I get:

> print  newPath.currentPosition,newPath.speed    AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'currentPosition'

Please let me know what could be the problem.